# Receive file name from user and assign each number in the file to a separate array

Tags: java

I'm simply just trying to receive the file name from user input then go through the file and assign each number in the file to their assigned array then print it out. I am also suppose to read the first line to know how many students/lines there are to read then.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;

public class A7LakshmanaSilva {

public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat ("#.#");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    final String chartSize = "%-11s%-12s%-11s%-12s%-13s";

    int sum1=0;
    int sum2=0;
    int i=0;
    int[] students;
    double [] mterm, finale, grades;

    System.out.print("Input file name: ");
    String inFile=scan.nextLine().trim();
    File myfile = new File(inFile);
    Scanner input= new Scanner(myfile);

    int n= input.nextInt(); //total students in class
    students = new int[n+1]; //student code
    mterm= new double[n+1]; //midterm grade
    finale= new double[n+1]; //final grade
    grades = new double[5]; //letter grade counter(irrelevant in this question though)

    System.out.println(String.format(chartSize,"Student","Midterm","Grade","Final","Grade"));
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------");

    if (input.hasNextLine()) {
    //String line= input.next(); //been testing with this
    //Scanner linescan= new Scanner(line);
        students[i]=input.nextInt();
        mterm[i]=input.nextDouble();
        finale[i]=input.nextDouble();
        ++i;
    }

    for(int j=0;j<n;j++) {
        System.out.println(String.format(chartSize,students[i],mterm[i]," ",finale[i],"Grade"));
    }

}
```

I should be getting the values from the file but instead I'm just getting 0 every line.

The file(grades.txt) :

```
 25
 000001 82  80
 000002 76  71
 000003 90  86
 000004 68  71
 000005 70  81
 000006 68  59
 000007 92  94
 000008 85  79
 000009 72  71
 000010 79  91
 000011 69  61
 000012 55  58
 000013 59  62
 000014 87  81
 000015 90  82
 000016 77  74
 000017 81  73
 000018 95  89
 000019 75  75
 000020 72  81
 000021 89  88
 000022 94  94
 000023 78  72
 000024 65  67
 000025 78  69
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you're errors are twofold.

**Firstly**, you did not properly load the arrays:

```
if (input.hasNextLine()) //If statement does not iterate
{                        //Unfilled arrays are likely filled with the default '0' value.
    students[i]=input.nextInt(); 
    mterm[i]=input.nextDouble();
    finale[i]=input.nextDouble();
    ++i;
}
```

Should Be:

```
while(input.hasNextLine()) //While Loop iterate through the file.
{
    students[i]=input.nextInt();
    mterm[i]=input.nextDouble();
    finale[i]=input.nextDouble();
    ++i;
}
```

**Secondly**, you're using `i` instead of `j` in your print loop

```
for(int j=0;j<n;j++) {
    System.out.println(String.format(chartSize,students[i],mterm[i]," ",finale[i],"Grade"));
}
```

Should Be:

```
for(int j=0;j<n;j++) {
    System.out.println(String.format(chartSize,students[j],mterm[j]," ",finale[j],"Grade"));
}
```

Comment: thank you I've been stuck on this for a while I don't know why but I guess I should have just reviewed over my code to spot out the semantic error.